# Write database function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have some psql function writen in my database that I often use in a different context of my python application (for data integration for example).

For an example, this is a simple function I wrote, but I have some others much more complex:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION                                 
    ref_nomenclatures.get_cd_nomenclature(myidnomenclature integer)
      RETURNS character varying AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE thecdnomenclature character varying;
      BEGIN
    SELECT INTO thecdnomenclature cd_nomenclature
    FROM ref_nomenclatures.t_nomenclatures n
    WHERE myidnomenclature = n.id_nomenclature;
    return thecdnomenclature;
      END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
```

On the other hand I have a python flask application which use sqlalchemy. All my models are declared with sqlachemy and I create my database with the `create_all()` function (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html).

How can I write those functions in sqlachemy and reflect them in my database with the `create_all()`  function ?
I would like to achieve that in order to write creation/migration script in python without writing any sql script.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be possible with alembic, https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#replaceable-objects